# TextBlock.TextDecorations can't be evaluated after reload of serialized XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm programming a WPF application in which i drop controls like the TextBlock from a toolbox-window to another designer-window.
After the drop i can open a Settings-window by right-mouse-click and set properties like TextDecorations = Underline with a togglebutton, so the text in the textblock has an underline or not.
In my case i set true.
When i reopen the Settings-window once more, the following code finds out, if the text has an underline and sets the IsChecked-state of the togglebutton for underline.

```
private void SetTextDecorationsFromElement(FrameworkElement element)
{
    SetUnderlineIsChecked = false;
    if (element.GetType().GetProperty("TextDecorations") != null)
    {
        var textdecoration = (TextDecorationCollection)element.GetType().GetProperty("TextDecorations").GetValue(element);
        var expectedValue = TextDecorations.Underline;
        SetUnderlineIsChecked = textdecoration == expectedValue ? true : false;
    }
}
```

Then i save my designer-window by XML-serialization.
When i open the XML again and make a right-mouse-click to the textblock with the underline, the code above doesn't work anymore as expected.

So i tried this code from an older question in this forum, but it even doesn't work.

```
private void SetTextDecorationsFromElement(FrameworkElement element)
{
    SetUnderlineIsChecked = false;
    if (element.GetType().GetProperty("TextDecorations") != null)
    {
        var textdecoration = element.GetType().GetProperty("TextDecorations").GetValue(element) as TextDecorationCollection;
        SetUnderlineIsChecked = (textdecoration == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) ? false :
            textdecoration != null && textdecoration.Contains(TextDecorations.Underline[0]);
    }
}
```

`textdoration.Contains(TextDecorations.Underline[0])` returns always false.
And even `textdecoration.Equals(TextDecorations.Underline)` don't help.
As i see - after the reload - the TextDecoration can be found in textdecoration[0].Location but TextdecorationLocation can't be converted to TextDecorationCollection.

Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i have found a way but i'm not sure if this is the right way.

```
private void SetTextDecorationsFromElement(FrameworkElement element)
{
    SetUnderlineIsChecked = false;
    if (element.GetType().GetProperty("TextDecorations") != null)
    {
        var textdecoration = element.GetType().GetProperty("TextDecorations").GetValue(element) as TextDecorationCollection;
        SetUnderlineIsChecked =
            textdecoration == null ? false :
            textdecoration == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue ? false :
            textdecoration != null && textdecoration.Count == 0 ? false :
            textdecoration != null && textdecoration[0].Location.ToString() == "Underline";
    }
}
```